# How to use searchView WITHOUT ListView or RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout with three textViews inside it. I am inflating a View (called cell)  programmatically and adding data to the textViews. When I run my app it looks like a typical ListView or RecyclerView. Now, I am tryin to use searchView. I can't seem to find an example how seachView in android is used without a ListView or RecyclerView. Can someone show me how to use seachView without ListView or RecyclerView and how I can use search to filter through my LinearLayout and the textViews thats inside them.

Comment: SearchView is just an EditText, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have something like this

**Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Editext for Search -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/list_view_linear"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

You logic should look like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // List view
    private LinearLayout lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"your list"};

        lv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_view_linear);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
            lv.addView(item);
        }


        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. How would the ArrayAdapter<String> adapter class look? and what are these methods: getFilter().filter()?

Comment: [Array adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) check this